# Acer Aspire Video Ad plays loudly when computer falls asleep

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire

When my windows 7 Acer Aspire Desktop falls asleep about every third time I get an ad for Acer Aspire Desktops with loud music. I used to just get the audio for about five minutes, Now I get the Audio and Video that does not stop. I have to keep headphones plugged in so there is peace in my home. Once I hit the keyboard it stops.

Comment: Did you tried changing screensaver?

Comment: Did you happen to purchase a display model? This sounds like the kind of ads they use in-store.

Comment: I do not have a screensaver on it. This was not a display model but you are right it seems like one.

Comment: WOOHOO! I looked and there WAS an ACER screen saver on my computer. I deleted it and I think this will stop the problem. Thanks so much for your help.